# How to make a singleton class BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

Suppose we have to use a single object of a class throughout the lifetime of an application. In BlackBerry 10, is it possible to declare a global object, which can be used anywhere inside the program?

Comment: http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/126713-global-variable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that, but a better way may be to use a class designed to be a singleton:

Singleton.hpp

```
class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton();

public:
    virtual ~Singleton();
    static Singleton &instance();

    int getMemberField() { return m_memberField; }
    void setMemberField(int mf) { m_memberField = mf; }

private:
    static Singleton    *p_instance;

    int                 m_memberField;
};
```

Singleton.cpp

```
Singleton*    Singleton::p_instance = NULL;

Singleton::Singleton() {
    p_instance = this;
    m_memberField = 0;
}

Singleton::~Singleton() {
    p_instance = NULL;
}

Singleton&    Singleton::instance() {
    if (p_instance == NULL) {
        p_instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return *p_instance;
}
```

In application code

```
Singleton::instance().setMemberField(25);
Singleton::instance().getMemberField();
```

The real benifit of this is that the singleton looks after its own global pointer.

Comment: Is this thread safe? Does it guarantee destruction? (My understanding is no to both)

Comment: You are correct, it is not thread safe as written. Would guaranteed destruction be compatible with the requirement to exist for the life of the program? Feel free to modify my examples to add those features if you are so inclined.

Comment: I understand guaranteed destruction to mean that the dtor is called -- e.g. what if I acquire some external resource in the ctor and release it in the dtor? I don't believe you will see the release happen here.

Example at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13615/c-templated-singleton-class-properly-destroyed

However I am unsure if that requires C++11 (I've seen that stated elsewhere on the internet, but not in the post).

Comment: Also, not that it is relevant to the question, but I personally would avoid singleton and the comment made by Loki is apt: `Best to create the object in main and pass it as a parameter to everything that needs it.`